# Dynamic query to dynamic data

Tags: oracle, dynamic

I am new to the oracle database, I am trying to execute the following query

```
select o.id as ovaid ,
(case when(select count(m.cid) from ovamapper m where m.id = o.id and m.solutionid = 1)>0 then 1 else 0 end) as sol1,
(case when(select count(m.cid) from ovamapper m where m.id = o.id and m.solutionid = 2)>0 then 1 else 0 end) as sol1,
(case when(select count(m.cid) from ovamapper m where m.id = o.id and m.solutionid = 3)>0 then 1 else 0 end) as sol1 from ovatemplate o order by o.id
```

Instead of static values for solutionid , I would like to select it from other table.

Any help on this is really appreciated

Comment: Please provide table schema for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

you could use

> join

to table that contain the solutionid. ex

```
Select * from ovatemplate JOIN solutiontable ON (solutiontable.ovaid=ovatempate.ovaid)
```

after that, change the static values to solutionid

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select  o.id as ovaid ,
        count(case when solutionid = 1 then m.cid else null end) as sol1 , 
        count(case when solutionid = 2 then m.cid else null end) as sol2 , 
        count(case when solutionid = 3 then m.cid else null end) as sol3
from    ovamapper m , ovatemplate o
where   m.id = o.id
group by o.id
order by o.id
```

If you dont need the aggregations as columns you should probably do that instead

```
select  o.id as ovaid , solutionid , count(*) as sol
from    ovamapper m , ovatemplate o
where   m.id = o.id
and     m.solutionid in (1,2,3)
group by o.id , solutionid
order by o.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ...but in the above query the solutionids are static ... I want the solutionids from a different table like  "select solutionid from table2"